# Remove Last Element from a List in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
List<String> path = Arrays.asList(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().split("\\\\"));
System.out.println(path);
int removeJavaFile = path.size() - 1;
path.remove(removeJavaFile);
String filePath = path.stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n)).collect(Collectors.joining("\\\\"));
System.out.println(filePath);
```

I was trying to get the directory in which my program is, and ended up using this to get the path to the file. I thought of getting the path, and then splitting it to later remove the file name from the path to get the directory, but failed to do so, despite using the `.remove()` method. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: To quote the Javadoc: “A Path representing an empty path is returned if first is the empty string and more does not contain any non-empty strings.”

Comment: `System.out.println(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath());` should display the path to your project directory. I'm wondering why you are overdoing it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash it  won't actually. It will display the path to the current directory. If that's the project directory, it's a happy accident that shouldn't be relied upon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

```
pathToFile.getParent()
```

### `Path#getParent`

No need to resort to crude string manipulation. Java NIO abstracts us away from the platform-specific details.

Call [`Path#getParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent()) to get another path object while dropping the last element of the original.

```
Path pathToFile = Paths.get( "SomeFolder" , "SomeFile" ) ;
Path pathToFolder = pathToFile.getParent() ;
```

### `List#removeLast`

By the way, to answer the title of your Question…

In Java 21+, `List` is a sub-interface of `SequencedCollection`. This brings convenient new methods such as [removeLast](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#removeLast()).

```
myList.removeLast() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you might be getting the UnsupportedOperationException, this is happening because you have used the Arrays.asList method, by using which the list cannot be modified i.e. no elements can be added or removed from the path list.

So, to perform your desired operation, you can use the below code.

```
String[] pathArray = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString().split("\\\\");
        List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll(path, pathArray);
        System.out.println(path);
        int removeJavaFile = path.size() - 1;
        path.remove(removeJavaFile);
        System.out.println("Path: "+path);
        String filePath = path.stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n)).collect(Collectors.joining("\\\\"));
        System.out.println(filePath);
```

Here, first you get the pathArray and then add those array elements into a list which can be modified which makes you remove the last element from the list.